# gzip not working for .js file larger than 1mb

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, gzip

I have 2 .js files, in exact same folder/location etc, and I use `.htaccess` from html5 boilerplate which ensure all asset files are gziped.

Yet one of them gets and other are not gziped.

//gziped correctly (saving 70% of its size !)

`https://riadaischool.com/js/app.5.01.js`

while

`https://riadaischool.com/js/lib.5.2.1.js`

is served as is with no compression.

why would such behavior happen both files are in same server/folder and same `.htaccess` rules should be applying to both?

Comment: Try adjusting `mod_gzip_maximum_file_size` and `mod_gzip_maximum_inmem_size` in gzip settings. Refer: http://www.schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/config.htm